# Segmentation fault(core dumped) trying very large numbers on sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++

I have to find how many numbers smaller than a given N are prime numbers, `N <= 5 * 10 ^ 7`
I tried to declare the numbers `long long`, `int long`, and I receive the segmentation fault error for very high values..
 Code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long  long int counter;
void SieveOfEratosthenes(long long int n)
{
    bool prime[n + 1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

    for (long long  int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
    {
        if (prime[p] == true)
            for (long long  int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
    }
    for (long long  int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            counter++;
    cout << counter;
}
int main()
{
    long long int n;
    cin >> n;
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool prime[n + 1];` is a good Ka-BOOOOM! candidate if `n` is large. Stack--wait for it!--overflow.

Comment: Assuming your compiler has a non-standard "variable length array" extension, your very large array on the stack is likely causing a stack overflow.  Hey, this website is **named** after a stack overflow!

Comment: how do I make it work for values so high then?

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) allocates from the free store, and the free store's limits are generally bound by the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, according to my gdb, the segfault occurs right in `memset` (testing with N = 10000000):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554999 in SieveOfEratosthenes (n=10000000) at soe.cpp:8
8       memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
```

This is immediately after the array initialization, so it's, in effect, "bad out of the box". The problem is that you're declaring a huge array on the stack, and there's not enough memory for that in there. You *ran out of memory*.

To get access to the rest of your computer's memory, you need to create an array on the *heap*. The best way to do this in most cases is to use the standard C++ library class `std::vector`. After declaration, it effectively works just like an array, but it does the memory management for you. You can also do it more "directly" by using `malloc` or `new`, but then you have to manage the memory yourself (in particular, you will need to `free` or `delete` it when done, before the function returns, since if you don't do that, you will get a "memory leak": at least as long as the program is running, there will be a block of memory hanging around, possibly quite large, that nothing can be done with until your operating system reclaims it after the program stops because you lost the pointer to it. While *likely* not to be a problem here, it's not something you want to let happen in more serious applications.).

Of course, the program will still eventually fail once you get to the absolute limit of your computer's memory, so you should include further handling code (in particular, checking if the pointer returned by malloc or new is NULL, or if using std::vector, using a try/catch for the `std::bad_alloc` [IIRC] exception around the code in `SieveOfEratosthenes`) to handle this case gracefully (e.g. showing a "Not enough memory to perform a run that large" message).

ADD: Putting all these changes together, it should look like

```
//#include <bits/stdc++.h> don't use this include. Can be very harmful
// if you aren't careful. And can be very harmful even then.
#include <iostream> // list all of the headers you need
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // for std::fill, see below

using namespace std; // fyi. generally not good practice to use
                     // "using namespace std" lest it become a habit
                     // (e.g. what if you make another function called "fill"
                     //  below?)

long long int counter; // fyi 2. does not need to be global

void SieveOfEratosthenes(long long int n)
{
    try {
      vector<bool> prime(n + 1);
      fill(prime.begin(), prime.end(), true); // has same fx as memset.
      // could also use
      // vector<bool> prime(n + 1, true);
      // to allocate and fill at the same time.

      for (long long  int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
      {
          if (prime[p] == true)
              for (long long  int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                  prime[i] = false;
      }
      for (long long  int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
          if (prime[p])
              counter++;
      cout << counter << endl; // "endl" to give a newline to make it nice
    } catch(const std::bad_alloc &) { // prefer to catch by constant 
                                      // reference
      cout << "Sorry, not enough memory to do a run that large." << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    cin >> n;
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 : Wow! fixed.

Comment: You're a wizard 0.o

Comment: thanks for the tips, I am part of a programming course and we have to make algorithms, we used very little of the C++ language so far, basically just the iostream , vector, algorithm, math.h  library.. not many functions, it's an introduction to the fundamentals of programming, and they chose C++ for convenience. I don't fully understand the code above because the syntax is  different from what was presented, but the truth is that I just wanna be done with these algorithms so I can start OOP(in Java) and web I don't plan to be using C++ anytime soon after this course.. thx for helping!!

Comment: @nultype : Thanks. Java manages all memory automatically, so you won't have to worry about it there. However, I think it is still important to know how this stuff works, because you never know when you'll need it again - _or_ when the "automagic" memory management in languages like Java starts to cause you problems in some circumstances (to the extent I've used Java I haven't encountered them yet, but have heard they are out there).

Comment: One of my personal favorites: https://ideone.com/YWrLMI . When you migrate from C++ to Java make sure you brush up on what is and what is not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a prime array?

You should reverse the logic and start the counter at the maximum possible:

```
counter = n + 1
```

then on the line where you currently have `prime[i] = false`, you just `counter--`.

Also, after the line `prime[i] = false` you should break the loop.

Comment: *Why do you need a prime array?* `prime[i] = false` is a bit hard to do without it.

Comment: You have the germ of a good idea with the counter-- trick that is worth fleshing out better. The rest of the answer I'm either completely misunderstanding or is misguided.